# how to use two submit functions for update save form angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angular js for form save. after saved i loaded all data to the grid. data can edit using edit button. i am using two separate functions to save data.

check my form

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="saveEmpDetils(); update()"
      novalidate="novalidate">
    Name <input type="text" ng-model="user.name"/>
    Age  <input type="text" ng-model="user.age"/>
    City <input type="text" ng-model="user.city"/>

    <button type="submit">Save</button>
    <button type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
```

load data to the grid

```html
<table datatable=""   id="empDetialTable" dt-options="dtOptions"
       dt-columns="dtColumns"  class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>      
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th class="text-center">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="employer in employerDetailList">
            <td>{{employer.name}}</td>
            <td>{{employer.age}}</td>
            <td>{{employer.city}}</td>
            <td data-title="'Action'" class="text-center">
                <div class="btn-group-xs">                       
                    <a ng-click="editUser(employer)" target="_self"
                       class="btn btn-flat btn-xs btn-primary"
                       data-toggle="tooltip"
                       data-placement="bottom" title="Edit" tooltip>
                        <i class="ion ion-edit"></i>
                    </a>
            </td>                       
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

when i click edit button, data loaded to the form. i done it. when click the edit, save button should hide and update button should show. after click the update button, update function should only submit. how i do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far I understood, You need to update and save within same modal or form If I am not wrong.

So,

1. Although there can be multiple ways of doing it. Such as you can
   pass id of employer in routes for the employer you want to edit and
   validate if id exists then call edit function and if not then save
   function.
2. I suppose the save and edit is in modal then you can maintain a scope variable that suppose isEdit so you will have $scope.isEdit = false //initially and when user click on edit button set $scope.isEdit to true. Then validate if $scope.isEdit is true then call for update function otherwise call for save function.

Change this

```
<form class="form-horizontal"   ng-submit="saveEmpDetils(); update()" novalidate="novalidate">
```

to

```
<form class="form-horizontal"   ng-submit="saveEmpDetils();" novalidate="novalidate">
```

and your saveEmpDetails must be something like this

```
$scope.saveEmpDetails = function() {
    if ($scope.isEdit) {
       $scope.update() //your update function
    } else {
       //your save function
    }
}
```